# -bash: express: command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, express

After numerous attempts at installing Express, my only output has been as stated in the title. Your help would be much appreciated. Below is a list of commands I've tried.

With my working directory being the directory I want the app to be in,

Trying 'sudo npm install express', I get:

[sudo npm install express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdKqf.png)

Followed by 'sudo npm install -g express-generator, I get:

[sudo npm install -g express-generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbxo9.png)

Now, running 'express', I get:

"-bash: express: command not found"

I have read through the top answers of 4 to 5 posts to no avail. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not readable. I try to answer: you are on osx, I advice you to install nvm. You can make a google search. Then you can install node.js by: `nvm install node` and finally you can type `nvm use node`. This solves your sudo problem and you can install express-generator and other packages without a sudo.